# Dynamically changing less variables in .net

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, dotless

problem : i have to allow users to have different colors for buttons , icons , text color as per their preference using spectrum.js

i have tried to solve this using dotless for that i created a file .less and added all values. now issue is that i have to get values from databased based on loggedInuser and have to dynamically change

```
@back-color: blue;
@font-color: red;
```

to different values and this has to be done run time not compile time. i know it will cost me some delay but i dont know how to solve it other wise.

i have been thinking of different solution rather to have a less file why not on saving time i create a css file save in database and when user gets logged in  create a css file and inject in to header

```
<link href="~/Content/dynamic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

can some one help me or any suggestion regarding this??

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
Implement special handler for resource, that represent css customized by user.
This handler must:

1. Make lookup (by userId) to cache where already rendered less (i.e. css) is stored;
2. If cache has entry for requested user, then write css to response and finish handling of this request;
3. If cache has no entry for requested user, then render less for this user, store it in cache and go to step 2.

You also should remove/update cache entry when user changes his color theme.
You can implement cache as you wish: in memory, inside database or inside static files that named (for example) like %userId%.css.

**Option 2**
Instead of render less on server side (and consume server resources) you can render less on client dynamically.
Exmaple: http://jsbin.com/wiqosutexe/5/edit?html,js,output

1. Include lessjs http://lesscss.org/#download-options;
2. Provide less template to client script (get with ajax, include in script itself or somehow else);
3. Use user preferences to make substitutions to less template.
4. Render template and insert results (plain css) into dynamically created style tag.

Comment: basically user wldnt have option to change theme . i mean to say when user will use http://example.com/login/salman he will get his latest changes ( color,font icon colors) so if i go with option 2 that means user will first get default colors and then will get his preferred theme. and i cant go for cache as i dont know when user has made changes for his theme. thats why i prefer to do it on server side change less to css and get it on every F5  what you say is it rite way of doing it /?

Comment: Yes, option 2 is more suitable for single page app (where page reloads rarely). If you implement old-fashioned web app, then use option 1. If you can't determine when user change his theme settings, then you can implement simple cache where every record become outdated after N minutes.